# How Can I Make A Ray Cast From The Bottom of My Player

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I'm a beginner game developer and I'm making a top down 2D game. The player's collider is on the bottom half of his body, kind of like Stardew Valley. In order to detect when the player hits a tree, I cast a ray from the player to the mouse. The problem is that the ray casts from the middle of the player, which means when you're north of the tree, you can't hit it, and it just acts really weird. I need a way to cast the ray from the player's feet. Here's the code I have:

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, -0.35f, 0);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.DrawRay(playerRb.transform.position, mousePosition - playerRb.transform.position, Color.red);

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(playerRb.transform.position, mousePosition - playerRb.transform.position, 2.0f);

            var treeScript = hit.collider.GetComponent<TreeScript>();

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                if (hit.collider.tag == "Tree")
                {
                    treeScript.Break();
                    Debug.Log("Hit Tree");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding the "offset" variable to my playerRb position, and the game runs, but for whatever reason, the raycast doesn't work anymore. The offset works fine on DrawRay.

Comment: You aren’t using the offset for anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Physics2D.Linecast` instead. Other people have been having problems with this too, and they used linecast instead and it worked.

Try something like

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position + offset, mousePosition);
```

Comment: I should've mentioned in my question that I tried using the offset exactly like that, but for some reason it just doesn't work. When I do that it won't let me click it no matter where I stand

Comment: what does the debug ray show

Comment: When I add the offset to the playerRb position on DrawRay, I figured out that I also had to subtract the offset from the mouse position to make it line up. When I did all that, the DrawRay works exactly how I want it to. Since the actual Raycast takes a direction as the second parameter instead of a position, all I should have to do is add the offset to the playerRb position. However, when I do this, it just doesn't do anything. the code still runs, but the Raycast stops working